# Credit Card Validation and send over mail

Tags: php, credit-card

I have currently a booking website and I wish to put a form whereby the user inputs his credit card and expiry date.  The card is automatically verified and once everything is fine, I want the credit card number and expiry date to be send to an Email though PHP.

I have tried several methods, most using 3rd party validations like Stripe but I am still not getting it right.
Can you all suggest me how to do this?

Comment: Can you share your code where you are trying to validate?

Comment: I have no code right now and I asking for suggestions

Comment: Will they enter card details in the form you provided or else they will enter there details at the payment provider

Comment: in the form itself

Comment: To be clear, you're planning on sending credit card numbers with expiration dates through cleartext email? That puts you at some serious risk, as you're not protecting consumer credit card data. If you're accepting credit cards, you're responsible for understanding PCI Compliance, see https://www.pcicomplianceguide.org/pci-faqs-2/.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the webhooks avariable with the third party service you're using.
In this way, Stripe (for example) can send you the transaction datas in json format to a hidden URL. Then you can use those datas to send your email.
More information here : https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks

Note that thoses third party service will never give you the credit card number but only the 4 last digits. They also give you the expiration date.